# Previous / Next page link using wp_query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am working on a wordpress site wich has a custom post type called, let's say 'plops'. I only want to use this custom post type in the website. So in the index.php, I am looping through those with a WP_Query, here is the code :

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'plops', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'orderby' => 'desc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
?> 
// my template for the post...

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The thing is I want to implement an infinite scroll to this page, and for that I need to have pagination links. I tried to implement those with the `next_posts_link()` function, but can't make it work !
It just won't display any link, and I tried a lot of stuff, nothing seems to make it work...

if i go to mysite.com/worpress/page/2, My posts do display, but I get a 404 in firebug... weird...

Any ideas ? Would really appreciate help ! Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: What happens when you use next_posts_link()? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link

Comment: Have you checked to see if either your $label or $max_pages variables is invalid?

Comment: I did not pass any arguments in the function, leaving it at default state. And it wouldn't explain the 404 on `/page/2/` ...

Comment: Even though they may be related, it is best to think of them as two separate issues. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about next_posts_link(), so this question might seem stupid, but for the first issue: do you have enough posts to actually make a second page? For the second issue, what page does firebug give you a 404 for? A 404 can only be gotten if you are requesting a page, so you should be able to find the page's URL it is tossing the 404 for.

Comment: Well as I said, the 404 is for the `mysite.com/wordpress/page/2/`, but it still shows me the posts even if I typed in this same url ! that is why I think it is weird... And yes I have enough posts

Comment: Ahh, I see. I try to assume as little as I can :) I was thinking it might be doing some ajax or other linked-file request behind the scenes which would explain the 404 (such as a missing CSS or JS file). We're kind of at a crossroads though, as I need more information to help you. Could you update your post with some more information, like a link to the page, or more code?

Comment: I can't provide you with a link, because my project is confidential, and I'm not sure what other code would be helpful... I know it works if I use normal posts and a standard loop. But I guess you would have to hack a little when usin WP_Query and custom post types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long time since this question is posted, but for anyone who is looking for a way to achieve this in his/her own code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'plops', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order' => 'desc');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    // my template for the post...
}

previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer');
next_posts_link('Older &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages);

wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Note:** You have to pass the max number of pages to the `next_posts_link` function only.

Answer (score 2):

The fix below might help you - this worked for me.  It combines Chris Coyier's solution here with some help found in the comments.  [CSS Tricks Article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/)

```
//Fix homepage pagination
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type', 'paged' => $paged );

$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query( $args ); 

while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Comment: This worked well for me, however I had to add `global $wp_query` before the `$temp = $wp_query` line